# make aosp 8:..../packages/apps/Dialer/java/com/android/incallui/res/values-hy_strings.arsc.flat

Tags: android, android-source

I have a problem when I make the AOSP 8 on Ubuntu, below is the log and I don't know what is the reason it happen. Please have a look on the log:

> [ 60% 42230/70123] AAPT2 compile out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/A...kages/apps/Dialer/java/com/android/incallui/res/values-hy/strings.xml
>   FAILED: out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/APPS/Dialer_intermediates/flat-res/packages/apps/Dialer/java/com/android/incallui/res/values-hy_strings.arsc.flat 
>   /bin/bash -c "out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt2 compile -o out/target/product/generic_x86/obj/APPS/Dialer_intermediates/flat-res/packages/apps/Dialer/java/com/android/incallui/res/  --pseudo-localize --legacy packages/apps/Dialer/java/com/android/incallui/res/values-hy/strings.xml"
>   packages/apps/Dialer/java/com/android/incallui/res/values-hy/strings.xml:0: error: xml parser error: not well-formed (invalid token).
>
> [ 60% 42233/70123] target R.java/Manifest.java: Contacts (out/target/common/obj/APPS/Contacts_intermediates/src/R.stamp)
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>   15:54:25 ninja failed with: exit status 1

## Failed to build some targets (53:18 (mm:ss))

Answer (score 0):

The file located at `packages/apps/Dialer/java/com/android/incallui/res/values-hy/strings.xml` seems to be wrongly formated. Check if it contains XML correct header. It may be useful to compare it with `packages/apps/Dialer/java/com/android/incallui/res/values/strings.xml`